# Is it possible to insert your attribute in the HTML-tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to insert your attribute in the HTML-tag, and then refer to it?

For example, add an attribute group:

```
first <input type="radio" id="qwerty1" group="1" onClick="myclick();"><br>
second <input type="radio" id="qwerty2" group="2" onClick="myclick();"><br>
third <input type="radio" id="qwerty3" group="3" onClick="myclick();"><br>

<script>
function myclick() {
  alert(this.group);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is a common pattern, but typically custom attributes for data are prefixed: data-group="1"

Answer (score 3):

Better to use W3C standards attribute **data-***
[Read More on data- attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

```js
function myclick(control)
{
alert($(control).attr("data-group"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
first <input type="radio" id="qwerty1" data-group="1" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>
second <input type="radio" id="qwerty2" data-group="2" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>
third <input type="radio" id="qwerty3" data-group="3" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>
```

**Update using data() function of jQuery**

```js
function myclick(control)
{
alert($(control).data("group"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
first <input type="radio" id="qwerty1" data-group="1" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>
second <input type="radio" id="qwerty2" data-group="2" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>
third <input type="radio" id="qwerty3" data-group="3" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>
```

Comment: While using jQuery, you can also use the `.data()`-function to get custom data-attributes

Comment: That's a good one, I was not aware about `.data()`-function, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)** method for Plain JS.

```
function myclick(input) {
  alert(input.getAttribute("group"));
}
```

Also, you need to pass current object through function call.

```
first <input type="radio" id="qwerty1" group="1" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>
second <input type="radio" id="qwerty2" group="2" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>
third <input type="radio" id="qwerty3" group="3" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/4j03tm63/)**

If you use jQuery already,

Use **[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use user defined attribute, you can use data attribute. Something like :

```
<input type="radio" id="qwerty3" data-group="3" onClick="myclick(this);">
```

Then, to call this value, you can access it using .data() function as following.

```
$(function(){
  function myclick(el)
  {
    alert($(el).data('group'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `data-*` attributes as W3C standards.

```
<input type="radio" id="qwerty1" data-group="1" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>
```

Then you can access it by:

```
$("#qwerty1").attr("data-group");
```

And set it by:

```
$("#qwerty1").attr("data-group", "1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of each radio button click function, you can use jquery single click function to get a attribute values

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $("input[name='radio1']").click(function(){  
        var value = $(this).attr("data-group");
        alert(value);
    });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    .ra_label
    {
    cursor:pointer;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <label for="qwerty1" class="ra_label">first <input type="radio" id="qwerty1" name="radio1" data-group="1" ></label><br>
    <label for="qwerty2" class="ra_label">second  <input type="radio" id="qwerty2" name="radio1" data-group="2" ></label><br>
    <label for="qwerty3" class="ra_label">third  <input type="radio" id="qwerty3" name="radio1" data-group="3" ></label><br>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the clicked handler to pass current dom element object and the use it to get attribute values associated with it:

```
 <input type="radio" id="qwerty1" group="1" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>
```

JS:

```
function myclick(obj){
  alert($(obj).attr("group"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to our own attributes in HTML tags. But for safety use 'data-' prefix before your attribute name to avoid any problems with older browsers.

```
first <input type="radio" id="qwerty1" data-group="1" onClick="myclick();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This(Complete Javascript approach) :-

```
first <input type="radio" id="qwerty1" group="1" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>
second <input type="radio" id="qwerty2" group="2" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>
third <input type="radio" id="qwerty3" group="3" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>

<script>
function myclick(elem) {
  alert(elem.getAttribute('group'));
}
</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hk7s7u3y/)

**Side Note :-** Instead of using `group` attribute this way use HTML5 `data-*` attribute as `data-group="1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get value like this:-

```
first <input type="radio" id="qwerty1" group="1" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>
second <input type="radio" id="qwerty2" group="2" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>
third <input type="radio" id="qwerty3" group="3" onClick="myclick(this);"><br>

<script>
function myclick(elem) {

 var value_gp =  $(elem).attr("group");

alert(value_gp);

}
</script>
```